# What do you use to render text from <textarea> to <div> with ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, textarea

What do you use? `Replace()` linebreak chars with `<br>`?  what about spaces? like maybe replace 2 spaces with `&nbsp;`?

`ParagraphFormat()` sucks.

`paragraphformat2()`?  http://www.cflib.org/udf.cfm/paragraphformat2

Comment: What is the intention here, to have the line breaks show properly inside the textarea field? Where is the text coming from originally, and how is it stored in the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ReplaceNoCase(someString,  "\n", "<br>","all")
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `Replace(someString, "\n", "<br>", "all")`?

Comment: Only if you want "<br>" to show in the textarea field. The Original answer would convert HTML BR tags to newline characters that a textarea field would properly read.

Comment: oh you're right... sorry, brain fart.  I updated the question.

Comment: I guess it would be the other way around.  The wording was a little confusing.

Comment: does "\n" take care of both linebreak styles (windows / *nix)?

Comment: In working with reading in text files, I have found that just looking for CR produces different results when reading in a windows file than other files. As another alternative solution I have used jQuery to manage line breaks because it natively works out the differences and treats them the same universally.

Comment: I would imagine that in a windows file that uses \r\n it would leave the \r.  I can't remember ever seeing this cause a problem but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may have to take into account is that different OS treat line breaks differently. Windows uses CR/LF while OS X and Unix use CR. I have used a code block effectively in the past to manage the different possibilities when it comes to reading in text files. Same principles could apply here. It's not 100% perfect, but on the rare occasions it has failed me it was because of an odd method of how the file was created. I modified it to fit the general idea of what you are going after.

```
<cfset variables.CRLF = findnocase(variables.textFromTextarea,"#chr(10)#") />
<cfif variables.CRLF>
    <cfset variables.textFromTextarea = replaceNoCase(variables.textFromTextarea,"#chr(10)#","<br>","all") />
<cfelse>
    <cfset variables.textFromTextarea = replaceNoCase(variables.textFromTextarea,"#chr(13)#","<br>","all") />
</cfif>
```

The idea here is that you are looking for the windows-only LF. If found, replace on it. Otherwise replace on the CR. Maybe that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to replace text from a textarea input to html when output on a webpage, and preserved the line break. So based on the accepted answer, I simply modified it to this, and it worked:

```
ReplaceNoCase(someString,  Chr(10), "<br />","all")
```

Hope that helps anyone else.